# MVC The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Ticket_dbo.User_UserID"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

I'm creating a ticketing system where users will go on the ticket page and create tickets when they have issues.
It is an MVC4 with EF6 web application and I've been having errors which I can't solve due to lack of knowledge on MVC.

I've been following instructions from a person:

In my previous version of my code I had another drop down list for User but was advised that it was wrong.

> Your creating a new ticket and that ticket should be assigned to the
>   current user. The current user should not be able to create a ticket
>   for another user. You should not evenhave a dropdownlist for that
>   property. You only assign the value of Author (or UserID`) in the POST
>   method just before you save the data model.

So I took out my drop down list for user as you can see from the second image below. I also added `Author = model.UserID,` when I create my ticket:

```
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket
        {
            Author = model.UserID,
            Issue = model.Issue,
            IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
            CategoryID = model.CategoryID
        };
```

> Your first if (!ModelState.IsValid) is correct except that you need to
>   change the ConfigureViewModel() method to also create the SelectList's
>   for Categories. Then you create the Ticket data model and you need to set all
>   its properties including CategoryID.

So I added the code below which should be a SelectList or categories in my ConfigureViewModel method.

```
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(u => u.CategoryName);
    model.CategoryList = categories.Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.CategoryID.ToString(),
        Text = a.CategoryName.ToString()
    });
```

> Then once you call db.SaveChanges() you need to redirect. There is no
>   point calling return View(); and if you do then it will just start
>   throwing errors because you have not populated the SelectList's.

This part I wasn't so sure about "redirect". If I delete return View()  I get an error on `public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)` saying `TicketController.Create(TicketVM)`not all code paths return a value`

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Ticket_dbo.User_UserID". The conflict occurred in database
>   "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext", table
>   "dbo.User", column 'UserID'. The statement has been terminated.

[image]
[image]

TicketController.cs (POST METHOD SNIPPET)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers
{
    public class TicketController : Controller
    {
        private IssueContext db = new IssueContext();

        //
        // GET: /Ticket/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            TicketVM model = new TicketVM();
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
            ViewBag.AllUsers = db.Users.ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem() { Value = u.UserID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", u.FirstMidName, u.LastName) });
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Ticket/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)   
        {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ConfigureViewModel(model);
                return View(model);
            }

            Ticket ticket = new Ticket
            {
                Author = model.UserID,
                Issue = model.Issue,
                IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
                CategoryID = model.CategoryID
            };

                db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
                db.SaveChanges();


            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", ticket.CategoryID);
  //          ViewBag.AllUsers = db.Users.ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem() { Value = u.UserID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", u.FirstMidName, u.LastName) });
 //           ViewBag.AllAdmins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).Include(u => u.Tickets);
            return View(ticket);
        }

        private void ConfigureViewModel(TicketVM model)
        {
            IEnumerable<User> admins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
            model.AdministratorList = admins.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.UserID.ToString(),
                Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstMidName, a.LastName)
            });
            IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(u => u.CategoryName);
            model.CategoryList = categories.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.CategoryID.ToString(),
                Text = a.CategoryName.ToString()
            });
        }
```

Views\Ticket\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.TicketVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticket</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IssuedTo, Model.AdministratorList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Issue)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Issue, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Issue)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!CHANGES TO CODE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

TicketController.cs

```
public class TicketController : Controller
{
    private IssueContext db = new IssueContext();

    //
    // GET: /Ticket/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tickets = db.Tickets.Include(t => t.Category).Include(t => t.User);    
        return View(tickets.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Ticket/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ticket);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Ticket/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        TicketVM model = new TicketVM();
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Ticket/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)   
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket
        {
            //UserID = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
            // Author = model.UserID,
            Issue = model.Issue,
            IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
            CategoryID = model.CategoryID
        };

            db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    private void ConfigureViewModel(TicketVM model)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> admins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
        model.AdministratorList = admins.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.UserID.ToString(),
            Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstMidName, a.LastName)
        });
        IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(u => u.CategoryName);
        model.CategoryList = categories.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.CategoryID.ToString(),
            Text = a.CategoryName.ToString()
        });
    }

    //
    // GET: /Ticket/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.AllAdmins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).Include(u => u.Tickets);
        return View(ticket);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Ticket/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Ticket ticket)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(ticket).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.AllAdmins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).Include(u => u.Tickets);
        return View(ticket);
    }
```

Views\Ticket\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.TicketVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticket</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category")
        </div>


        <div class="editor-field">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, Model.CategoryList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IssuedTo, Model.AdministratorList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Issue)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Issue, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Issue)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Q1: See note on your other question (and remove `ViewBag.AllUsers = ....` from the GET method

Comment: Q2: Your revised code in the `ConfigureViewModel()` method is correct except remove `ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(...)` from the GET method and POST method and change the view code to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, Model.CategoryList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })` and move it inside the form tags.

Comment: Q3: Change `return View(ticket);`to `return RedirectToAction("Index");` (or what ever view you want to display once you have successfully saved the `Ticket`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you verify that I followed your instructions correctly? I'll do some studying with the web security login first because I need to add ID to my ticket model before I know if it works or not.

Comment: How can I verify your new code without seeing it :)

Comment: I actually commented out the code you told me to remove but doesn't matter. I've re-edited the question.

Comment: FGS. Did you even read my comments (to Q2 and Q3). And you cannot change the original question (the revised code has no relationship at all to the question) and I have rolled back your changes.

Comment: I did ! Initially I just commented out the lines of code you want me to remove because I wanted to show you the changes but you rolled the changes back. When you look at the code again it's has if I didn't apply Q2 and Q3 because they are back to the old code.

Comment: I rolled it back because you cannot change the intent of the original question (for obvious reasons). And you did not follow my instructions. If you want to post a link to you updated code (say on PasteBin) then I will look at it for you.

Comment: Fair enough. When you said you needed to see it to verify it, I thought you wanted me to re-edit the changes. Q2 I deleted all ViewBags.CategoryID = new SelectList and I added  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, Model.CategoryList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" }) in my View\Ticket\Create.cshtml   http://pastebin.com/E6Asihd5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106824/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jason-wan).

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that in table Ticket_dbo you are trying to insert a user id into column User_UserID but that user id does not exist in table dbo.User. This is how foreign key constraints work. Therefore, make sure you insert the user into the database first or check if that user exists, if not, then handle the situation according to your requirements.

> Then once you call db.SaveChanges() you need to redirect. There is no point calling return View(); and if you do then it will just start throwing errors because you have not populated the SelectList's.

Yes he/she is right. You should not simply return a view. But send a redirect so the browser can get another page. [Here](http://sampathloku.blogspot.ca/2013/05/how-to-use-prg-pattern-with-aspnet-mvc-4.html) is how and why you should do that.